# The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Tags: sql, jdbc

I'm using **SMSS 2014 (12.0.2000.8) and also SMSS 2016**.
The JDBC Driver is **mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11**.

This is the output after I compile the code:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]". ClientConnectionId:6d1bbfa9-5e53-47fa-b07e-42f6df640d65
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2998)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1884)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2558)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2067)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1204)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:825)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
        at Connector.initializeConnection(Connector.java:20)
        at Connector.<init>(Connector.java:10)
        at mainApp.main(mainApp.java:5)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]     
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:363)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:319)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:310)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:951)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:873)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:456)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1383)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1296)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:416)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:388)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1802)
        ... 10 more
```

I believe that I'm using TLSv1.2 and I did check in the regedit. Thank you for the helps!

Comment: Hi, your SSMS version not relevant, but it sounds like your SQL Server only supports TLS1.0, which is deprecated in Java 11. What SQL Server version are you running? Here is an article on making SQL Server support TLS1.2, maybe that helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the problem by deleting SQL server 2014 and setup a new SQL server 2016, then it worked fine. Also, I found that the SQL server browser service should be enable too.